# rotate function works in main and not when called - opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glfw, glm-math

so here is some opengl code on matrix transformations. the scaling and moving of the camera is working all fine, but the rotation part is not. what we are trying to do is rotate the camera around the object (in x and z) and that supposedly is done in the camera function, but when we call it the camera just goes up and down. when we use the same exact rotate code in main without calling a function though, the rotation works fine. what are we missing?

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;
using namespace std;


glm::mat4 ViewMatrix;
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); // added model matrix 

glm::mat4 getViewMatrix() {
    return ViewMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 getProjectionMatrix() {
    return ProjectionMatrix;
}

// Initial position : on +Z
glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 10, 0);

// Initial horizontal angle : toward -Z
float horizontalAngle = 3.14f;
// Initial vertical angle : none
float verticalAngle = 2.0f;
// Initial Field of View
float initialFoV = 90.0f;
float speed = 3.0f; // 3 units / second
float mouseSpeed = 0.005f;

float h = rand() % (9) + 2.0f;

float height = h / 2;

void camera_function() //shamelessly copied by controls (camera example) 
{
    // glfwGetTime is called only once, the first time this function is called
    static double lastTime = glfwGetTime();

    // Compute time difference between current and last frame
    double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    float deltaTime = float(currentTime - lastTime);
    
    // Get mouse position
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

    // Reset mouse position for next frame
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024 / 2, 768 / 2);

    // Compute new orientation
    horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed * float(1024 / 2 - xpos);
    verticalAngle += mouseSpeed * float(768 / 2 - ypos);
    
    // Direction : Spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates conversion
    glm::vec3 direction(
        cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle),
        sin(verticalAngle),
        cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle)
    );

    // Right vector
    glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(
        sin(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f),
        0,
        cos(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f)
    );

    // Up vector
    glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, direction);

    float r = 45.0f;
    // Move forward
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD) == GLFW_PRESS) { //zoom in 
        position += direction * deltaTime * speed;
    }
    // Move backward
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT) == GLFW_PRESS) { //zoom out
        position -= direction * deltaTime * speed;
    }

    // rotate right - problem here
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) { 
        r+=5;
        glm::mat4 SMatrix = glm::rotate(SMatrix, glm::radians(r), glm::vec3(1,0,0));
        ModelMatrix = SMatrix;
        //change to rotation for axis x
    }
    // rotate left - problem here
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_X) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        r-=5;
        glm::mat4 SMatrix = glm::rotate(SMatrix, glm::radians(r), glm::vec3(1,0,0));
        ModelMatrix = SMatrix;
        //change to rotation for axis x
    }
    // Move up
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS) { 
        position += up * deltaTime * speed;
        //change to rotation for axis z
    }
    // Move down
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Z) == GLFW_PRESS) { 
        position -= up * deltaTime * speed;
        //change to rotation for axis z
    }
    

    float FoV = initialFoV;
    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FoV), 4.0f / 4.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Camera matrix
    ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
        position,           // Camera is here
        position + direction, // and looks here : at the same position, plus "direction"
        up                  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    // For the next frame, the "last time" will be "now"
        
    );
    lastTime = currentTime;


}

// loadshaders was given, i have not written it so the post isnt too long

int main(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    const char* title = u8"\u0395\u03c1\u03b3\u03b1\u03c3\u03af\u03b1\u0020\u0031\u0392\u0020\u002d\u0020\u03a4\u03c1\u03b1\u03c0\u03b5\u03b6\u03bf\u03b5\u03b9\u03b4\u03ad\u03c2\u0020\u03a0\u03c1\u03af\u03c3\u03bc\u03b1";
    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 1000, title, NULL, NULL);




    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);


    // Dark green background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);


    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders


    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("ProjBVertexShader.vertexshader", "ProjBFragmentShader.fragmentshader");


    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 4.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Camera matrix
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(10.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    );
    // Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    // Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around

// also removed vertex buffer data - was given


    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLuint colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    do {


        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);
        
        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();


        glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
        float sz = 1.0f;


        /* problem here, this method only works when in main - not when called as camerafunction


        float r = 0.0f;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            r += 5;
            ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, glm::radians(r), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));


            //change to rotation for axis x
        }
        */
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_U) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            sz = sz + 0.01f;
            ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, sz));
            

        }


        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_P) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            sz = sz - 0.01f;
            ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, sz));
            

        }


        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        camera_function();


        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );


        // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );


        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,  12 * 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle


        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);


        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();




    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);


    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);


    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();


    return 0;

}
```

we tried initialising the model matrix somewhere where it was visible by every function, and that failed, then tried to initialize it in camera function but pressing the keys just did nothing. we think there is some variable that we are missing or one that is in main that we don't have in the camera function, but it all seems to match up.

Comment: How do those `glm::rotate()` calls even *compile*?

Comment: it does indeed compile (all of the code) but in all honesty this is my second opengl program so i can't say why or how.

Answer (score 2):

your float r = 45.0f; is defined locally in rotate function , so it  is always created every frame and the value is never incremented.

float r = 45.0f  make it a global variable or make it static.